# UnsatisfiedLinkError while importing java project with JNI Files in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk, java-native-interface

I am getting this error while trying to import an android library (.aar ) with JNI Files ( lib-native.so native libraries. )

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.cryogeneye.test-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.cryogeneye.test-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libnative-lib.so"
                                              java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.cryogeneye.test-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.cryogeneye.test-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libnative-lib.so"
                                                  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
                                                  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
                                                  at android.example.com.arsdkdevop.TrillCoreSDK.<clinit>(TrillCoreSDK.java:123)
                                                  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
                                                  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273)
                                                  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
                                                  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)
                                                at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$2.queueIdle(Unknow
```

While the same library (.aar ) is working fine on a new android project.

My aim is to import an android library (.aar) containing JNI files (.so) in Unity Project.

Answer (score 1):

This may be useful for others.

When you use the aar with your project, your project don't get those **.so** files. At least it was so in my case.

New project just with aar would work like a charm but when I add any external library it would throw the same exception.
I added the entire jniLibs that I had on my exported project to the new project and things went fine after that.

This is how my structure looked like after adding jniLibs.
[image]

and this is my Gradle.
[image]